# Rails 5 - table row while no entry exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails app, content of documents are being tagged. For documents that do not have any tags, an empty row is shown in the listing (table rows) - always at the bottom of the table. I've tried to solve this for hours, not sure where to research and I'm not getting anywhere. All help welcome!

this is the view (snippet):

```
<div class="row" id="annotationResults">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: white;  word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 0.9em;">
        <table id="tags" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tagged content</th>
                    <th>as</th>
                    <th>in</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% @annotation.tags.each do |tag| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= tag.content %></td>
                    <td><%= tag.tagtype_id %></td>
                    <td><%#= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to '', [tag.annotation, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your `@annotation` activerecord contain empty data?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's really expected behaviour that theres no `tr` at the end.

Comment: @Vucko - tags can only be added to existing annotation records (the annotation record has an attached PDF. Siegy - no, there is no error message or so and yes, the expected behavior is that there are no '<tr>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there because you're printing an empty `td`.

```
<td><%= tag.content %></td>
```

Will print the `td` element even if the `tag.content` is empty. Check the example:

```css
td{ border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use your RoR snippet as you mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718646/rails-5-table-row-while-no-entry-exists/39719199#comment66735696_39718761):

```
<% @annotation.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <% unless tag.content.blank? %>
    <td>
      <!-- logic -->
    </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: tx Vucko; may be related: on the same snippet, you see '<td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>' - it throws an no method error. On other places where I use it, this works. Any idea why?

Comment: It the `tag.tagname` is empty, or nil, then `name` method will throw an error.

Comment: OK; yet, it is not empty or not nil; 100% sure. Tagtype is object which is associated to Tag-object; and the field name is mandatory field on Tagtype.

Comment: wait - in previous case it was empty or nil - stupid me :-)

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<% if tag.content.present? %>
  <%=  tag.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: no difference; actually the row should not be there.

Comment: '<% @annotation.tags.each do |tag| %><% unless tag.content.blank? %>' will hide the row. Yet, why is it even there in the first place?